# Covariance of process $X(t) = \int_{t}^{t+1} W(s)\, ds$, where $(W(t))$ is a Wiener process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $X(t)$ be the following time integral of a Wiener process $W(t)$
$$
X(t) = \int_{t}^{t+1} W(s)\, ds.
$$
This process is zero mean, and I want to compute its covariance $EX(t)X(s)$.

**I am not sure that the following is correct.** It is obvious that if $|t-s|>1$ then $EX(t)X(s) = 0$.
In the case when, for definiteness, $t \leq s \leq t+1$ we can consider the following partition
$$
\Delta_1: t=a_0<a_1<\ldots<a_n=s,
$$
$$
\Delta_2: s=b_0<b_1<\ldots<b_k=t+1,
$$
$$
\Delta_3: t+1=c_0<c_1<\ldots<c_l=s+1.
$$
Each corresponding Riemann sum can be represented in the following way
(here $a_{-1}=0$ by definition)
\begin{align*}
R_{\Delta_1} &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} W(a_i)(a_{i+1}-a_{i})\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (W(a_{i-1})-W(a_i))a_{i} + W(a_{n-1})a_n\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (W(a_{i-1})-W(a_i))(a_{i}-a_n).\\
\end{align*}
And now using the independence of increments we have
\begin{align*}
E (R_{\Delta_1}+R_{\Delta_2})(R_{\Delta_2}+R_{\Delta_3}) 
&= E (R_{\Delta_2})^2\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k (b_i-b_k)^2 E(W(b_{i-1})-W(b_i))^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k (b_i-b_k)^2 (b_{i}-b_{i-1}).
\end{align*}
And 
$$EX(t)X(s) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^k (b_i-b_k)^2 (b_{i}-b_{i-1})
= \int_{s}^{t+1} (y-t-1)^2dy = \frac{(t+1-s)^3}{3}.$$
Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[X(t)X(s)]&=\mathsf{E}\left[\int_t^{t+1}W(r)dr\int_s^{s+1}W(q)dq\right] \\ &=\mathsf{E}\left[\int_t^{t+1}\int_s^{s+1}W(r)W(q)dqdr\right] \\
&=\int_t^{t+1}\int_s^{s+1}\mathsf{E}[W(r)W(q)]dqdr \\
&=\int_t^{t+1}\int_s^{s+1}\min\{r,q\}dqdr.
\end{align}

If $s\ge t+1$, then
$$
\mathsf{E}[X(t)X(s)]=\int_t^{t+1}rdr=t+\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! So the rest is also wrong because $ER_{\Delta_1}R_{\Delta_2}\ne0$, right?